# Compare Location coordinates on Android

Tags: android, location, compare

We want our application to get location data when user opens the Activity and check if it's inside a certain boundary of location.
We are able to get the Coordinates of the current phone location now we want to compare it that if it is inside a building location or not. How do we check if the coordinates (lat Long) of the phone is inside a specific radius range?

thanks

Comment: It is not clear what the question is. Probable reason for the down votes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use google's Geofence API.

new Geofence.Builder().setCircularRegion(latitude,longitude,radius);

https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html